# Microsoft RDC "Negotiating credentials" takes unusually long (3-4 mins)

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I'm using a Mac Mini at home to remote into my Windows 10 computer at work. We use a RD Gateway server (RDP over HTTPS) to remote in. When I click to remote in from home, "Negotiating credentials" takes an exorbitantly long time....about 3 to 4 minutes. None of my other workstations or the servers have this issue, just the Win10 machine.

**What are the registry settings and/or local GP settings that control this?** I know it's just an issue on the Win10 machine, but do not know how to address it. Thanks.

EDIT: My suspicion is that the user "hacked" away at the registry and messed it up. The user was a dev that admitted he was trying a "universal termsrv" patch to use the machine like a terminal server (against MS EULA) - multiple RDP logins concurrently.

Comment: I'd try the new RDC Mac Beta before struggling with the old one - significant improvements - https://rink.hockeyapp.net/apps/5e0c144289a51fca2d3bfa39ce7f2b06/ [yes, that's a real MS link] *edit* & the announcement link https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/30/remote-desktop-client-preview-for-mac-supports-multiple-monitors-and-more/

Comment: Thank you, Tetsujin. I can try the new program but, **I am almost certain this is an issue with the Win10 (RDP host) machine**, not MS RDC for Mac (or anything on my Mac). The reason I know this is I can remote into other workstations and servers on the same domain at work and it connects *within seconds*!

Comment: Bump. Anyone???

Comment: Sigh....no one? Maybe I should post to ServerFault?

Comment: The way to add interest is to post a bounty on the question [though that needs more rep], comments don't draw attention to anyone except the last comment poster. Did you try the beta? Or do you have logs of the errors?

Comment: Thank you, Tetsujin. I cannot upgrade RDC on the Mac, it breaks multi-monitor support: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/677595-os-x-remote-desktop-v8-0-10-breaks-multi-monitor-support-old-version-anywhere

Comment: However, I am positive this is an issue with the Win10 machine, not RDC or anything on my Mac. This is why I posted here in SU instead of the AskDifferent forum.

Comment: ...then logs are needed... otherwise it's just guesswork. btw, that link is two years out of date.

Comment: Ok, I will check logs on the Windows machine. Which ones exactly? Also, I just checked from my wife's MacBook (running RDC v8.0.36, latest) and the issue is exactly the same.